# C++ how to force NTP update every few minutes and check if the update was successful

Tags: c++, time, synchronization, ntp

I am writing a piece of code for a small device that has to perform cyclic NTP synchronization with an interval of 1 minute (more or less).
So this is what I do:

```
sntp_setoperatingmode(SNTP_OPMODE_POLL);
if(sntp_getoperatingmode() != SNTP_OPMODE_POLL){
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error setting SNTP operating mode...");
    return false;
}
sntp_setservername(0, (char*)NTP_SERVER);
sntp_init(); 
time(&now);
localtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
while(timeinfo.tm_year < (2018 - 1900)){
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // give some time to NTP...
    time(&now);
    localtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
}
sntp_stop();
```

First NTP synch is easy and goes well, from the second synch the problem will be that the system time will already be more or less equal to what I expect (for sure the tm_year value) so I do not have a way to understand if the new synch with NTP is working or if I am still reading the system time set at the previous iteration (for example 1 minute before).
Is there any way to tell if NTP is synchronizing correctly?

For sure I could set the system time in the past just before beginning a new synch with NTP so the condition on tm_year would hold but I would like to preserve the integrity of the system time just in case of a failure by NTP.

Any idea?

EDIT: I have many devices that must do the same thing at the same time so I need them to be synchronized as frequently as possible with the same NTP server. Since I can't suppose to have access to a real NTP server (because my devices won't be always connected to the web) I wrote a function that at the beginning tries to synch only on a server from the NTP pool, then I try with a local server (that I know to be always reachable). Obviously the problem is that all devices must synch with the same NTP server and I must be able to check if the synch with the real NTP server was successful or not before going on with the optional query to the local NTP server.

Comment: That seems to be an excessively frequent update rate for a time sync that 's typically only good to a couple milliseconds. If you can let us know why you're doing this maybe someone can offer a better suggestion.

Comment: You should really only by synchronizing with an NTP when your internal clock gets out of sync. If you clock is getting out of sync once a minute that sounds like a problem that should be resolved properly. Also if you need to sync multiple devices together, why not just sync them together instead of relying on an NTP.

Comment: How close together is "at the same time" for you? if it's milliseconds, NTP isn't good enough. If it's tenths of seconds NTP  might be good enough. If it's seconds, you're probably doing just fine.

Comment: I want to monitor particular packet traffic on wifi, so I have a bunch of ESP32 boards that monitor the network and each minute send some data to a computer that makes statistics with the data. Each board must label each captured packet with a timestamp, so let's say packet P must be labeled with the same timestamp by all boards. Accepted error (timestamp difference between different boards) is around 100 ms. I tried simply to synch each board indipendently with a NTP server and everything works perfectly. I can't suppose to be always connected to internet so…(see next comment)

Comment: I can't suppose to be always connected to internet so I designed a three-step synch where at the first attempt I try with a real NTP server, the second attempt is done with a local NTP server (the same PC that collects data from the boards and elaborates them) and finally if NTP does not work I have another function to syncrhonize manually the boards with the PC. The main problem is that I need to be able to check if the query to the real NTP server was successful in order to decide if I need to query the local NTP server and then, if NTP didn't work at all, to perform manual synch.

Comment: You may be better off always using the PC as the timing master. All of the nodes reaching across the Internet increases the likelihood of the nodes receiving greatly different times, but if everyone gets their time from a master over a controlled local network, the real time might be a little more skewed because the master isn't a high stratum time server (but it could be with a little work!), but the times on the nodes will have a much more predictable path to the local master and should be much more tightly synchronized with that master and each other.

Comment: If the Internet is lost and the master starts to drift, the nodes are still kept in synch with the master and share a common time base without potentially a big hic-up when switching from Internet time to the local master (they're always on the local master) and no switch-over makes for a simpler system.

Comment: Well I managed to add a couple of lines in the source code of LWIP which is the library used by the ESP32 board to implement the "networking stack", with this modification each time the SNTP procotol gets the correct time from the server I set a flag, so I am able to check if SNTP was successful or not. Then I decided to keep the previous scheme (NTP from pool, local NTP, manual synch) only because this is an assignment for a course in my university and the specifications clearly say that the system should work also in absence of internet connection and a local server is not mentioned...

Comment: Moreover I can't suppose to have a local NTP server because I am working on Windows so to set up the Windows Time service also as NTP server I need to modify the registry, add inbound and outbound exceptions to the firewall on UDP port 123 and so on....this is something that I can do to test the system but if the user (the professor that evaluates the project in this case) tells me that he does not want to open ports on his pc and so on well I am screwed so I need to keep a backup plan and that's it: go for NTP from NTP pool, if failure go to local NTP, if NTP not available synch manually.

Comment: And incredibly I must say it works well and I see that timestamps (related to the same packet, let's say probe request by a specific device that uses its real MAC address) put by different boards are coherent with a time difference in general of 3\4 milliseconds but most of the time they are within 2 milliseconds of difference....and frankly this is strange, I did not think that NTP was good enough to synch devices with this precision in fact at the early stages I didn't even consider the possibility of using NTP for this task.